# Can MAUI class library be used in non-MAUI app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, maui

I create a Maui class library named (MauiLib.dll), and I want to reference it in an existed application written by WPF or C++/Win32, will that be possible?

I've search it for days and didn't find much useful information. I tried to directly reference MauiLib.dll in a WPF application (.net 6.0), but there is a compile error :

> error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not find assembly
> 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'.

I've also tried CLR/C++ and [.NET host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/netcore-hosting) to call method in MauiLib.dll hoping to show a window, they all result in the same error,

> could not find assembly 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Are there some configurations needed to set?

PS: Oh, my application runs only on windows, using Maui or WinUI3 is a try to newer technology than before : )

Comment: Is there anything MAUI specific about your library?  If not, then just use a normal .NET library project

Comment: I want to use the newest UI technology on WIndows. @Jason

Comment: That won’t work

Comment: Does it mean new UI technology on windows like WinUI3 or Maui, cannot work together with old technology like WPF or Win32? @Jason

Comment: Yes, cannot work together @NormalTerancel

Comment: *"newest UI technology on Windows."*: Make a `Windows Desktop App` project, rather than a `Maui` project. That should be your main project. If your goal is to embed older Windows UI code (WPF, WinForms), look for solutions that update those to .net 6. I do not recommend trying to get your existing old project to be the main (.exe) project. Instead, read how to update that old code for .net 6. Then try moving a small amount of that code into your new Windows Desktop App (aka WinUI 3) solution. After that experiment, evaluate whether this blending is likely to succeed. There will be difficulties